# complex sphere deformations

Tags: modeling

I am trying to design this chair, the base is very easy.
[image]

What I'm struggling with is the weird cut in the middle, do I manually have to move vertices? if so, i will have to apply my subsurf 1st? Just a little lost.
[image]

Mesh

[image]

Comment: Please show your work as a Blender Screen capture in this question and all future questions.  Please show your mesh model.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the image above are three stages of the mesh. Left to Right. Hemisphere.  Hemisphere with a loop cut and delete vertices.  Last mesh image has subdivision surface modifier.

---

- Create enough vertex density appropriate to the model.  Because there is a deep recess with edges near each other you should consider the object as possessing protrusions .. or arms.
- Remove Vertices for flowing face density if possible
- Hemisphere from sphere
- Loop Cut for more density.  This prepares for the deep cut.  You can barely see how the Z height of the cut face area is now half of the surrounding face z height.  Thus allowing more detail.  Loop Cut can be searched.
- Delete vertices on Both Sides.  This will allow the deep cut while keeping regular vertex density.
- Consider Proportional edit or Lattice to shape the mesh.
- Subdivision Surface Modifier
- Modify and Improve to your tastes
- You are the Artist and can improve the crude mesh depicted above

[image]

- Most forward mesh to viewer has used proportional edit.  Proportional edit may be searched here at BSE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should begin with a rather basic mesh, then add all the necessary edges, then put *Solidify* and *Subsurf* modifiers:

[image]